# Retrieving data from third model in database using primary keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, primary-key, join

I would like to access the current user's albums by using the primary keys in the Schema below. I have  User, Band, And Album models as follows...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :bands
end
```

---

```
class Band < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :albums
  has_many :users
end
```

---

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :band
end
```

Schema as follows...

```
create_table "albums", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "releaseDate"
  t.string   "artWorkUrl"
  t.integer  "band_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "bands", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "user_id"
end

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
  t.string   "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

and am trying to use the following method in the Albums controller...

```
def albums
  @albums = current_user.bands.albums
end
```

Sorry, i'm sure this is a noob question. I know this should be a simple primary key access through the user --> bands --> albums, using user_id and band_id but have been unable to populate the current users albums through bands. Any insight in much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def albums
  band_ids = current_user.bands.map(&:id)
  @albums = Album.where(band_id: band_ids)
end
```

By separating the queries you do not have the `n+1 problem`: [What is SELECT N+1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-issue)

Comment: That's great - thanks, the n+1 explanation was enlightening as well.

Comment: First row: "I would like to access the current user's albums"

Comment: Okay - I was looking at the associations. Mind if I post the answer that I was working on?

Comment: I think SO would benefit from more answers.

Comment: :) I posted anyway lol. I agree with your `n+1` statement but would prefer to stick to convention

Answer (score 1):

> by using the primary keys

You should be looking at the [`foreign_keys`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) (`primary_keys` are when you reference the same table). So what you're really asking should be *how do I set up the Rails associations correctly for my models?*

Here's how:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :bands
end

#app/models/band.rb
Class Band < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :albums
    belongs_to :user
end

#app/models/album.rb
Class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :band
end
```

This will allow you to call `current_user.bands.first.albums`

--

**Notes**

You have to remember the `bands` association will be a `collection`. This means you can't just call `....bands.albums`. Instead, you'll need to loop through the array like this:

```
<% for band in current_user.bands do %>
   <%= band.albums.inspect %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You're right - I'm slowly learning (been at ruby/rails for about 6 weeks or so) that I need to think harder about architecting my models/association before jumping into a project. Thanks for taking the time to answer the question.

Comment: No problem! Rails is amazing - congrats on sticking with for 6 weeks!! What is your goal with it?

Answer (score 0):

In user class define one more association

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base    
  has_many :albums, :through => bands
end
```

In your controller

```
@albums = current_user.albums
```

Comment: This will not work, `band` does not act as the join table in this case.

Comment: that's why I've added `has_many :albums, :through => bands` to user model, worth giving a try ;)